# Do new routes require a static first portion?

Tags: 8, routes

Using mymodule.routing.yml, I can successfully create a custom route at /foo/{bar}/{baz}, but I cannot use /{bar}/{baz} or /{bar}/foo/{baz} as path for a route; they just return a 404 error.

Why? Is there any way to create a route for /{bar}/{baz} (with strict requirements for bar)?

I've read the entirety of [the routing API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system) and I can't seem to find any answers.

Comment: "Do new routes in Drupal 8 *require* a static first portion?" - yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the routing system you can't do this. What you can do is path aliasing.

Inbound: `/{bar}/foo/{baz}` -> `/foo/{bar}/{baz}`

Outbound: `/foo/{bar}/{baz}` -> `/{bar}/foo/{baz}`

You need a pattern to apply a regular expression on the path inbound, so `/{bar}/{baz}` is only possible if the parameters themselves have a distinctive pattern.

I didn't find a tutorial how to build a path processor, but you can use the 
[PathProcessorFront](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21PathProcessorFront.php/class/PathProcessorFront/8.8.x) class as example.

Register both as tagged service in the .services.yml file for the module.

```
services:
  path_processor_front:
    class: Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 200 }
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
```

Comment: Awesome, that even answers the next question I was going to ask!

Answer (score 3):

See [Routing System on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes).

> Path (required): The URL to the route, with a leading forward slash (e.g., path: '/book'). You can use dynamic properties by including them in curly braces. (e.g., path: '/node/{node}/outline'). These will be passed along as arguments via parameter converters to the controller/form (see below). **Note that the first item of the path must not be dynamic.** You can also define optional parameters at the end of your path (See 'Optional Parameters' on this page).

I hope this is enough to understand that routes cannot start with a slug.  It must be a static value.

Comment: Voting up for the attempt, but screenshots aren't very useful to this community, I suggest a quote instead, this may be why you received a downvote.

Comment: Yep. I've added some emphasis to the bit that really answers the question too.