# Dynamic language negotiation by multiple top level domains

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am porting www.example.com, the German version is at de.example.com, the French is at fr.example.com and so forth. I could enter these domains in `admin/config/regional/language/detection/url` but I would like them to be subdomains: if one visits www.example.test then (www,de,fr).example.test should work, and if one visits www.example.local then (www,de,fr).example.local should be the translated domains and so forth. It seems I need to make the results of `$config = $this->config->get('language.negotiation')->get('url');` dynamic. I am at a complete loss at how to implement this:

1. I could write an entirely new plugin based on `LanguageNegotiationUrl`. If I started with a copy of it, I could drop `processInbound` and half of `getLangcode` but the rest would need to stay -- and given how little change needs to happen, that's a lot of code to keep in sync with core.
2. I could patch `LanguageNegotiationUrl` factoring out the four `$config['domains']` interactions into a method and then extend accordingly. Much less maintenance pain than the previous one but at the same time, it's a core patch. Of course, composer-patch applies them after updates but still, a core patch for this?
3. I could write a config override which overrides `language.negotiation` but it seems the overrider doesn't get the data loaded. So I'd need to get the domain map from somewhere else, for example by re-reading it from the config storage. That's really, really wasteful.
4. I could write a "super saiyan config override" by decorating the config factory service so when the `language.negotiation` is `get()` then do something with it, like put the dynamic overrides in `setModuleOverride`. OK, that's not a lot of code, great, the proxy script will write most of it, even better, but now *all config calls* are a hair more complex and a hair slower.

Any clean ideas I missed...?

Comment: I wouldn't rewrite or patch core code. You could add your own path processor with a higher priority to handle the domain stuff before the path reaches the language negotiation.

Comment: *Intriguing*. Care to expand this into an answer? From what I see in `LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound`, the domain is not available separately, all that code is busy reconstructing `base_url`.

Comment: have you investigated https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like the perfect use case for environment specific configuration. No runtime changes required. Just like you would swap the email addresses in your environments that are used to send emails and would swap the API keys in dev/test environments, you would swap this configuration there as well. You could use something like https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split for example.

Answer (score 1):

1. `config_split` I have multple problems with: one is philosophical, having multiple branches of config sounds like a good way to complicate deployments where you need to make sure the right config gets to live. The other is practical, the team is big and fluid and everyone needing to configure the domains to their preference is not ideal.
2. If I resolve to not touch the actual negotiating code (which would be very highly desirable) then the path processor is a no-go because `LanguageNegotiationUrl::getLangcode` calls `$request->getHost()`. And `Request::getHost` is not a simple getter of a property (tellingly there's no `setHost`) rather it calculates the host every time from various headers so this manipulation would need to replicate and fight this logic unsetting this , setting that... This is another no-go.

I ended with writing a class proxying `ConfigFactory` and a service provider injecting this right into the negotiatior service:

```
public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
  if ($container->hasDefinition('language_negotiator') && $_ENV['SMARTSHEET_SITE_ENVIRONMENT '] !== 'prod)') {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('language_negotiator');
    if ($definition->getClass() === 'Drupal\language\LanguageNegotiator') {
      $definition->replaceArgument(2, new Reference('sd8.language_config_factory'));
    }
  }
}
```

and then the SubdomainConfigFactory does this:

```
public function get($name) {
  $config = $this->configFactory->get($name);
  if ($name === 'language.negotiation') {
    $domainSuffix = preg_replace('/^[^.]+/', '', $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getHost());
    $override['url']['domains'] = [];
    foreach ($config->get('url.domains') as $langcode => $domain) {
      $override['url']['domains'][$langcode] = strtok($domain, '.') . $domainSuffix;
    }
    $config->setModuleOverride($override);
  }
  return $config;
}
```

This is very far from ideal and I feel there must be a nicer way to work with dynamic config and I will post if I find out how.

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be overridden from your `settings.php` or `settings.local.php`.

```
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['en'] = 'www.example.test';
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['de'] = 'de.example.test';
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['fr'] = 'fr.example.test';
```

Which means, that you need to set them manually in every environment once. Each of your coworkers needs to adjust their `settings.php` or `settings.local.php` according their needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom path processor. To handle the domain path part before language negotiation you need to choose a priority inbound >300 and outbound <100, because these are the priorities of the language path processor:

```
services:
  path_processor_custom:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\PathProcessorCustom
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 310 }
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 90 }
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
```

For more information see [Do new routes in Drupal 8 *require* a static first portion?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246950/do-new-routes-in-drupal-8-require-a-static-first-portion)

Comment: Well, this only describes how to define a path processor, that's OK. But what do you actually do with it? A significant portion of `LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound` seems to be just that -- reconstructing `base_url`. And if I am my own processor then I actually need to implement a `LanguageNegotiationUrl::processInbound` and so I do not readily see how would this end up with less code than doing option #1 from the question. (I would also like to point out I have asked the exact same in the comment on the question.)

Comment: If you set the priority <100 your outbound path processor runs after LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound or any other language negotiation plugin and you only need to change the top level domain in `$options['base_url']`.

Comment: I am a bit wary of re-parsing `$options['base_url']` but I guess something like https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/url would make it more solid -- and if the domains configured are the production domains then it could be ran only on non-production.

Comment: My answer is about a better way than 1 - 4 of your question to override the result of path processing in language negotiation. It's not about for which cases this is useful. If you want to do this only for local dev, then you can override the language config in settings.local.php: `$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['de'] = ...`.